# Why does LibreOffice Calc change CSV file Character Set?

Tags: windows, csv, libreoffice-calc, character-encoding, ascii

I have a `.csv` file export (actually printed to csv file) made on a Windows 10 machine. Working in Libreoffice Calc on Archlinux, Why can Calc open a file using settings `Character Set: Western Europe (ASCII/US)`, but saved file and reopened, the file acts like `utf-8`?

Save As settings:

- Name: `[something]`
- Choose Format: `Text CSV (.csv)`
- Edit filter settings: `Character Set: Western Europe (ASCII/US)`

By trial and error, I found an alternative to ASCII filter setting which does appear the same through the cycle: `Character Set: Western Europe (Windows-1252/WinLatin1)`

Any ideas why?

---

A little background. I'm doing some Python scripting with Juypter Notebooks to generate import files and the application requires ASCII TDF. There are special characters which the app uses which I can't alter and must be present in the import file. I'm testing the import using Calc csv files, before testing the script output. I need to be sure each step doesn't bork the ASCII characters. Calc is part of that process.

Comment: "*Why **can** Calc*" do that, or why **does** Calc do that?

Comment: Ok. Google defines `would` as: _"2. indicating the consequence of an imagined event or situation"._ I can change it if it sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

Calc should ask for the Character set on import.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I saved my csv file,I just use the edit filter and just used the Unicode (UTF-8 
) character set option and that worked just perfectly for simplekml to read the file correctly with no errors.